# FRM-91500: Unable to start/complete the build when trying sudo su - oracle -c to run frmcmp_batch.sh

Tags: oracle, unix, sudo, oracleforms

I was trying to automate our form compilation process.
I created a `.bat` file that will do the following:

1. Login user to host
2. `sudo -S -u oracle bash -c 'bash /frmcmp_batch.sh'`

But when I try to run `frmcmp_batch.sh`, I'm getting the error:

> FRM-91500: Unable to start/complete the build error.

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Support account? If so you should have a look at *note 756384.1 - Known Causes of FRM-91500 Error In Forms*.. Otherwise this is a fairly generic error which usually indicates some problem with the environment configuration. For instance, [this advice from PITSS](https://pitss.com/us/2012/10/08/frm-91500-compiling-oracle-forms-linux/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your display isn't right. You get this to work by setting the following commands:

> export TERM=vt220
>
> export ORACLE_TERM=vt220